# How to avoid "Uncaught TypeError" here?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, node-sqlite3

```
const userDetails = (id) => {
  console.log(id);

  const row = connection
    .prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = ?")
    .get(3435);
  console.log(row.userName, row.userEmail, row.userPassword);
}
```

My code works but if I enter wrong value

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')

returns from `console.log`. How do I avoid this condition?

Answer (score 0):

[.prepare](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statement)'s  signature is as follows: `prepare(sql [, param, ...] [, callback])` and it returns a statement.

Therefore it will not return a row of data. Instead you'll have a [statement](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statement) which has various methods such as `.each` and `.all` of which, you should be able to use like so:

```
const stmt = connection.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = ?");

stmt.get(id, function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.userName, row.userEmail, row.userPassword);
});
```

Comment: I did when came like that  "SQLite3 can only bind numbers, strings, bigints, buffers, and null
    at D:\st system\new one…s\customer.js:84:12 "

Comment: What is type is id?